# Re-Adding Keys to Github

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I removed my SSH Keys in an effort to backtrack a little bit. When I went to re-add them I got "Oops! The key has already been taken. " Even though I obviously just removed the key it was referring to.

It seems the system just doesn't update itself right away. Anyone know how long it takes to remove the keys from my account so that I can put them back up?

Or am I wrong and I am missing something? I tried SSH'ing into git@github.com, and it refered to the name I use to add my keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried emailing github support and explaining your problem?

Failing that, either the system will timeout and you can upload the old ones again or you will need new keys - I don't know exactly what github's restrictions on old keys are.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when trying to add my id_dsa.pub key; id_rsa.pub worked just fine.

Too bad the error message diagnosed the wrong problem (incorrect key type). A better error message would have saved me a trip to the googles.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a new key, you cant just delete the old and re upload it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is which key are you copying to GitHub!
You have to copy the PUBLIC KEY. Usually is the .pub file!